# How to determine if internet connection is available?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

How can I determine if an internet connection is available in windows store app?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`NetworkInformation` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br207293.aspx) to detect that; this sample code adds an event handler that is called every time connection status changes;

```
NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += 
    NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged; // Listen to connectivity changes

static void NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged(object sender)
{
    ConnectionProfile profile = 
        NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

    if ((profile != null) && profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() >=
                NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
    {
        // We have Internet, all is golden
    }
}
```

Of course, if you want to just detect it once instead of getting notified when it changes, you can just do the check from above without listening to the change event.

Comment: Also note you can get quite a bit more advanced with this in detecting network states: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700376  and the ConstrainedInternetAccess listed here which may give 'some' level of access:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkconnectivitylevel

Comment: As @Cabuxa.Mapache noted, this answer doesn't check for profile != null, which happens everytime a connection is not available.

Answer (score 2):

```
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;      

public static bool IsInternetConnected()
{
    ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    bool internet = (connections != null) && 
        (connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);
            return internet;
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some context to your code to explain why your answer answers the OP's question.

Answer (score -5):

just wrote async functions to do that:

```
    private void myPingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
            return;

        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            //ok connected to internet, do something
        }
    }

    private void checkInternet()
    {
        Ping myPing = new Ping();
        myPing.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(myPingCompletedCallback);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
        int timeout = 1000;
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);
        try
        {
            myPing.SendAsync("google.com", timeout, buffer, options);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Worst answer I've ever seen in a lot of time dude... absolutely performance killer...

Comment: Also the code uses the Ping class, which isn't available to Windows Store apps, which the question is about.